# How can we load the folder into Big Query from Google Storage?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload all .csv.gz files stored in the google cloud storage folder.

I tried

bq load 
--skip_leading_rows=1 
--allow_quoted_newlines 
--source_format=CSV  
transfer_test.multiple_gzfile_test 
gs://test_compressed_file/* \

but it says no matches found: gs://test_compressed_file/*.

I also tried "gs://test_compressed_file/*", gs://test_compressed_file/*.csv.gz, and "gs://test_compressed_file/*.csv.gz", but none of them work.

Comment: Do the files and the bucket exist?  Do you have a recent version of BQ? did you try to update it?

Comment: 'gs://test_compressed_file/*.csv.gz' works.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are now able to load the csv.gz files into a BigQuery dataset.
According to [Google’s documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data#load-wildcards), the wildcard is used to match a pattern in the object’s name, therefore **gs://test_compressed_file/*** or **gs://test_compressed_file/*.csv.gz** should have worked. 
Based on the aforementioned, it is possible that the error was produced by a typographical-error in the URI declaration.

See replication below:

```
# Listing folders in bucket
$ gsutil ls -l gs://<bucket>/
gs://<bucket>/CSVs/
gs://<bucket>/Images/
gs://<bucket>/PDFs/

# Listing files in gs://<bucket>/CSVs/
$ gsutil ls -l gs://<bucket>/CSVs/
         0  2021-07-07T20:21:33Z  gs://<bucket>/CSVs/
        39  2021-07-07T20:22:24Z  gs://<bucket>/CSVs/table_1.csv.gz

# Using command with typo in URI and getting error:
$ bq load --skip_leading_rows=1 --allow_quoted_newlines --source_format=CSV test1.table1 gs://<bucket>/CSV/*
Waiting on bqjob_<BQ_JOB1> ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job '<project>:bqjob_<BQ_JOB1>': Not found: Uris gs://<bucket>/CSV/*

# Using command with correct URI
$ bq load --skip_leading_rows=1 --allow_quoted_newlines --source_format=CSV test1.table1 gs://<bucket>/CSVs/*
Waiting on bqjob_<BQ_JOB2> ... (1s) Current status: DONE   
$
```